# Grand Theft Auto V - Rockstar Game Services are unavailable

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online, rockstar-games-social-club

For some reason since today I can't connect to the rockstar game services anymore. When I launch my game I'm logged in succesfully and then socialclub keeps loading and ends up with this error:

[image: Rockstar game services unavailable]

Why was I able to play the game before? I didn't change anything in my windows or install any updates also I didn't change things in my router. After this error I have tried to port forward again wich didn't help. Also enabling/disabling UPNP didn't help.

I installed GTA on my second hard drive.

I'm not planning to reinstall GTA because of the size of the game and it looks like a network error.

Router: Technicolor TG789vn v3
OS: Windows 10 64 bit
CPU: Intel i7 4700mq
GPU: AMD HD8970M

Does anyone else have this error and does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you *read* the error message you're getting? It's almost certainly an issue on Rockstar's end.

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same problem and I found a temporary solution. Just change your connection/router, and the games load up.

Like I said, it's only temporary. My new connection now has the same problem

Comment: This isn't particularly helpful, since not everyone has other connections they can use.